# How to connect pickerviews and labels in iOS?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uipickerview

I have two `pickerView` and two `Label` on my `ViewController`.

The question is how I could connect `label`s to `pickerView`'s data array (string type) and show in `label`s chosen pickerView cell?

```
@IBOutlet weak var valuetype1: UILabel!

    var pickerData: [String] = [String]()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.picker1.delegate = self
        self.picker1.dataSource = self
        self.picker2.delegate = self
        self.picker2.dataSource = self

        pickerData = ["Годы", "Месяцы", "Недели", "Дни", "Часы", "Минуты"]
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    valuetype1.text = pickerData[row]
    valuetype2.text = pickerData[row]
}
```

How could you see I connected labels (`valuetype(1..2)`) to `pickerData` but it always show in both `label`s one String. I need to show in first `label` String chosen in `pickerView1` and another string in second `label`, chosen in `pickerView2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIPickerViewDelegate` has a method called `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)`. Add this method to your VC class. This method gets called whenever the user selects a row.

Your implementation should look somewhat similar to this.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    valuetype1.text = pickerData[row]
}
```

For more information refer to the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview

**EDIT:**

When you are using the same controller as a delegate for multiple UIPickerViews, then you can check which picker view triggered the method call simply by comparing the `pickerView` argument on the `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` method.

Try this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == picker1 {
        valuetype1.text = pickerData[row]
    } else if pickerView == picker2 {
        valuetype2.text = pickerData[row]
    }
}
```